# React, como puedo cambiar el estado de una variable de estado de un componente a través de otro

Tags: reactjs, usestate

Hola que tal tengo 2 componentes, el primero se llama `Search`, que contiene un botón que al hacer click en él, se encargará mediante una variable de estado booleana, determinar si mostrar o no el contenido (alternando display:none, y display:flex).

La función `handleShowAddNote`, se dispara con un `onClick`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {MdSearch, MdAdd} from 'react-icons/md'
import '../styles/Search.css'

const Search = ({ handleSearchNote }) => {
    const [showNote, setShowNote] = useState(true)
    const handleShowAddNote = () => {
        /* En los estilos por defecto, addnotes tiene display none */
        if (!showNote){ //Si es false oculta la nota
            console.log(showNote)
            document.querySelector('.note.new').style.display='none';
            document.querySelector('.notes-list').style.display='grid';
        }
        else{ //Si es true muestra la nota
            console.log(showNote)
            document.querySelector('.note.new').style.display='flex';
            document.querySelector('.notes-list').style.display='none';
            
        }
        setShowNote(!showNote)
    }
  return (
        <div className='search'>
            <div className="input-wrapper">
                <MdSearch 
                    className='icon search-icon'
                /> 
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder='¿Qué nota estás buscando?'
                    onChange={(event) => handleSearchNote(event.target.value) }
                />
            </div>
            <div className="btn-wrapper-search">
                <button 
                    className='btn-addNote'
                    onClick={handleShowAddNote}
                >Nueva Nota</button>
                <MdAdd 
                    className='icon add-icon'
                />
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

Funciona bien, pero ahora tengo un problemilla, tengo otro componente (que es la nota que se oculta o se muestra) que se llama `AddNote` . En este segundo componente se retorna 2 botones, uno que es **guardar**, y otro que es **volver**. Ambos botones tienen que hacer el mismo efecto que el primer componente, que es ocultar la nota cuando guardamos o volvemos.

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/AddNote.css'
import { useState } from 'react'

const AddNote = ({ handleAddNote }) => {
    const [noteText, setNoteText] = useState('');
    const [classState, setClassState] = useState('note new');
    //const limiteLetras = 200; //esto luego se quita
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        //if (limiteLetras - event.target.value.length >= 0){ //esta condición luego se quita, no interesa
            setNoteText(event.target.value);
        //}
    }
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        if (noteText.trim().length > 0){ //comprueba que la nota tenga texto
            handleAddNote(noteText)
            setNoteText('');
            document.querySelector('.note.new').style.display='none';
            document.querySelector('.notes-list').style.display='grid';
            
        }
        else{
            setClassState('note new shake-right')
            setTimeout(()=>{ //necesario para reproducir la animación siempre que demos click y no haya texto
                setClassState('note new')
            },500)
        }
    }
    const handleReturn = () => {
        document.querySelector('.note.new').style.display='none';
        document.querySelector('.notes-list').style.display='grid';
    }
    return (
        <div className={classState}>
            <textarea 
                placeholder='¿Qué has aprendido hoy?'
                value={noteText}
                onChange={handleChange}>
            </textarea>
            <div className='note-footer'>
                {/* <small>{limiteLetras - noteText.length} Remaining</small> */}
                <button className='save btn' onClick={handleClick}>Guardar</button>
                <button className='return btn' onClick={handleReturn}>Volver</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default AddNote;
```

**Adjunto una imagen para dar contexto:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De la forma en que tengo planteado la funcionalidad, si hago click en añadir nota, me muestra la nota para empezar a escribir, si vuelvo a dar click en nueva nota, la oculta, ya que alterna su estado de true a false. Lo que ocurre es que si hago click en guardar, y se oculta la nota, su estado (lógicamente porque no está programado aún), no se alterna, por lo que al querer volver a añadir una nota, tengo que hacer 2 clicks, uno que cambia su estado a false (no ocurre nada), y otro para ponerlo a true, y volver a mostrar la nota.

¿Hay alguna forma en React de pasarle la variable de estado **[showNote, setShowNote]** del componente Search al componente AddNote?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: No veo el código completo de `AddNote`, en este caso si quieres que el estado se mantenga en true, solo pasa el hook al componente `AddNote(setShowNote)`, y dentro de tu click inicias el estado en true `setShowNote(true)`, y otra cosa, el hook setShowNote debe estar en tu componente padre

Comment: Hola, he editado los códigos, están los 2 componentes completos, pero no sabría decir si son padre e hijo.

Comment: de casualidad en `<MdAdd` no mandas a llamar a tu componente `AddNote`, porque no veo que llames tu componente `AddNote` en `Search`

Comment: MdAdd es solo un icono de la librería react icons, no sé muy bien a que te refieres con llamar a AddNote en Search, te refieres a importarlo?

Comment: si, a eso, pero creo que mejor deberías subir tu proyecto a GitHub para revisarlo mejor, si en dado caso no lo haces , creo que la solución sería que en tu componente `AddNote` agregaras nuevamente el hook `setShowNote` e iniciarlo en true al hacer click

Comment: hola Daniel, lo que me comentas creo que no lo puedo realizar o no termino de comprenderlo, tal vez mi planteamiento está mal partiendo de una base, estoy aprendiendo react y el comportamiento entre componentes aún me supera un poco jeje, te adjunto el repositorio donde está el código, si puedes echarle un vistazo sería genial Gracias. https://github.com/usupruebas/appnotes

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137579/discussion-between-juan-jesus-and-daniel).

Answer (score 0):

Mirando tu codigo en github, tu component padre seria **`App`** y tus componentes hijos serian **`Search,header,AddNote`**

entonces si buscas pasarle la variable de estado `setShowNote a true`
debes declarar tu hook  a tu component padre que seria **`App`**

```
const App = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
const [showNote, setShowNote] = useState(true)
 // el resto del codigo
}
```

y pasar las variable a los demas componentes, seria mas o menos de esta manera

```
const App = () => {
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
const [showNote, setShowNote] = useState(true)
//resto de codigo

return (
  <div className={darkMode ? 'dark-mode' : ''}>
    <div className="container">
      <Search handleSearchNote={setSearchText} setShowNote = {setShowNote}/>
      <NoteList 
      notes={notes.filter((noteText) => 
      noteText.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
      )}
      handleAddNote={addNote}
      handleDeleteNote={deleteNote}
      setShowNote = {setShowNote}
      />

    </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

y de esta manera podras usar la variable a tu component **`Search`** o **`NoteList (que seria component padre de AddNote)`**

```
const NoteList = ({ notes, handleAddNote, handleDeleteNote, setShowNote }) => {
return (
  <>
    <div className="add-notes-wrapper">
      <AddNote 
      handleAddNote={handleAddNote}
      setShowNote= {setShowNote }           
      />
      </div>
      <div className='notes-list'>
        {notes.map((note => 
        <Note 
          key={note.id}
          id={note.id}
          text={note.text}
          date={note.date}
          handleDeleteNote={handleDeleteNote}
        />
      ))}     
    </div>
  </>
  )
}
```

Component **`Search`**

```
const Search = ({ handleSearchNote,setShowNote  }) => {
    //resto del codigo
}
```

Comment: Gracias Daniel, he comprendido mejor como usar una variable de un componente en otro, de hecho de alguna forma funciona lo que estoy intentando pero yo sé que no es lo correcto, también me está tirando un warning el compilador porque la variable showNote está definida pero no usada, he hecho un apaño para evitar el warning pero siento que esto a futuros me dará bugs jaja. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @JuanJesús es porque te falta usarla en tu componente, solamente lo declaras `setShowNote (true)`, igual puedes pasar tu variable `showNote` como `setShowNote`, el warning que te da, es porque no estás usando tu variable, una es eliminarla o usar `/* eslint-disable */` antes de tu variable, eso te desactiva el warning